# Quasar vite doesn't return the ssrapp handler for my firebase functions

Tags: firebase, server-side-rendering, vite, quasar

I started a Quasar V2 app using the quasar CLI with vite config and ssr build. I can't seem to return the firebase functions handler from dist/ssr/index.js as suggested in the docs.

I've tried this with the webpack Quasar V2 config and it works fine.

I ran firebase init then installed firebase-functions and firebase-admin in the root dir.

I changed the source of functions to dist/ssr where I built my ssr app. I also edited hosting to send requests to the function "handler".

firebase.json

```
"functions": {
    "source": "dist/ssr",
    "ignore": [
      "node_modules",
      ".git",
      "firebase-debug.log",
      "firebase-debug.*.log"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/ssr",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "handler"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"]
  },
```

I then returned the handler function, following the instructions from the [quasar docs](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-ssr/ssr-webserver#serverless)

server.js

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const listen = ssrListen(async ({ app, port, ssrHandler }) => {
  if (process.env.DEV) {
    await isReady();
    return app.listen(port, () => {
      if (process.env.PROD) {
        console.log("Server listening at port " + port);
      }
    });
  } else {
    return {
      handler: functions.https.onRequest(ssrHandler),
    };
  }
});
```

I then ran "npm install" on both the root directory and the dist/ssr directory to make sure everything is fine.

then when I ran "firebase serve" I get back this result in localhost:5000 "Function us-central1-handler does not exist, valid functions are:" Whats going on :(